# How to solve this 404 Not Found error even though my route exist

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes, laravel-8

I have this route:

```
Route::get('orderview/{id}', [UserController::class, 'vieworder']);
```

and this is my form action:

```
 <td>
         <a href="{{ url('orderview/'.$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
 </td>
```

When ever i trigger this form action, it gives me Page not found and ive checked my route to confirm it the route is registered using:

php artisan route:list

ive also tried:

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:cache 

php artisan config:clear

php artisan optimize
```

But this problem still persist, please i need help.

Sorry, this is controller:

```
public function vieworder($id)
{
    $orders = Order::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    return view('frontend.orders.view', compact('orders'));
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the URL helper instead of the route helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function in your router like this:

```
Route::get('orderview/{id}', '[ClassNameSpace]\UserController@vieworder')->name('orderview');
```

Update: `[ClassNameSpace]` should be changed to your customer/global target class's namespace :)

Comment: @Mohammed H. - after i changed it to your solution, i got this error:   Target class [App\Http\Controllers\UserController] does not exist.

Comment: Could you share the namespace of `UserController`?

Comment: Thank God it worked- i had to change the part from  : App\Http\Controllers\UserController   To: 'Frontend\UserController@vieworder'...... also changing:  Route::get('orderview/{id}', [UserController::class, 'vieworder']);   To: Route::get('orderview/{id}', 'UserController@vieworder')->name('orderview'); thanks to everyone, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to

```
Route::get('orderview/{id}', '[namespace]\UserController@vieworder')->name('orderview');;
```

and use `route()` in your `href`

```
href="{{ route('orderview',['id' => $item->id]) }}"
```

Comment: Got this Error::::::;:   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [orderview] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\odjayshop\resources\views\frontend\orders\index.blade.php)

Comment: use your namespace in route